# Create parameter for switch in main method java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm new coding with Java and with any language at all. 
Let me apologise for my English. My native language is Spanish.

I created a switch in a class and I want to call it in the main but it comes with a parameter (0) and when I run it displays the default case "La opcion ingresada es invalida"

This is the main method:

```
public class Triwago 
{        
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Reservacion unaReser=new Reservacion();

        Reservacion.Bievenida();
        Reservacion.Reservacion();
        Reservacion.cantAdultos();
        Reservacion.cantNiños();
        Reservacion.cantNoches();
        Reservacion.switchReser(lugarhostel);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that I called from:

```
public class Reservacion {

    public static String Bievenida ()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido a Triwago\nA continuación el sistema le guiara por el servicio de reserva");
        return null;

    }

    public static int Reservacion ()
    {
        int lugarhostel;
        lugarhostel=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite 1 si desea reservar en playa o 2 para montaña"));
        return lugarhostel;
    }

    public static int cantAdultos()
    {
        int cantAdult;
        cantAdult=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de adultos:"));
        return cantAdult;
    }

    public static int cantNiños()
    {
        int cantNiños;
        cantNiños=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de niños"));
        return cantNiños;
    }

    public static int cantNoches()
    {
        int cantNoches;
        cantNoches=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de noches"));
        return cantNoches;
    }

    public static int switchReser(int lugarhostel)
    {
        switch (lugarhostel) {
            case 1:
            Reservacion.Playa(lugarhostel, lugarhostel, lugarhostel);
            break;
            case 2:
            Reservacion.Montaña(lugarhostel, lugarhostel, lugarhostel);
            break;
            default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion invalida");
            break;
        }            
        return lugarhostel;            
    }      

    public static int Playa(int cantAdult,int cantNiños,int cantNoches)
    {
        int precioAdult=10000;
        int precioNiño=7000;
        int preciototalAdult;
        int preciototalNiño;
        int preciototal;

        preciototalAdult=(cantAdult*cantNoches*precioAdult);
        preciototalNiño=(cantNiños*cantNoches*precioNiño);
        preciototal=preciototalAdult+preciototalNiño;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de adultos es: "+cantAdult+"\nLa cantidad de niños es: "+cantNiños+
        "\nLa cantidad de noches es: "+cantNoches+"\nEl precio a pagar por los adultos es de: "+preciototalAdult+
        "\nEl precio a pagar por los niños es de: "+preciototalNiño+"\nEl total a pagar es de: "+preciototal);
        return preciototal;
    }

    public static int Montaña(int cantAdult,int cantNiños,int cantNoches)
    {
        int precioAdult=10000;
        int precioNiño=7000;
        int preciototalAdult;
        int preciototalNiño;
        int preciototal;
        cantAdult=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de adultos:"));
        cantNiños=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de niños"));
        cantNoches=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de noches"));
        preciototalAdult=(cantAdult*cantNoches*precioAdult);
        preciototalNiño=(cantNiños*cantNoches*precioNiño);
        preciototal=preciototalAdult+preciototalNiño;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de adultos es: "+cantAdult+"\nLa cantidad de niños es: "+cantNiños+
        "\nLa cantidad de noches es: "+cantNoches+"\nEl precio a pagar por los adultos es de: "+preciototalAdult+
        "\nEl precio a pagar por los niños es de: "+preciototalNiño+"\nEl total a pagar es de: "+preciototal);
        return preciototal;
    }
}
```

I hope u can help me...this is my first question here

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  You're saying when you pass `0` into a switch statement that only has cases for `1` and `2` you get the default case...?  That's working as expected.

Comment: Can you have `ñ` in a function name?

Comment: @Coldspeed Yes You can have it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what is the problem, but perhaps it helps:

In the methods

```
Reservacion.Reservacion();
Reservacion.cantAdultos();
Reservacion.cantNiños();
Reservacion.cantNoches();
```

You are returning an integer. Which you made locally, in the specific method. For example cantNiños in:

```
public static int cantNiños(){
  int cantNiños;
  cantNiños=Integer.parseInt(...);
  return cantNiños;
}
```

cantNiños will be lost if you don't assign the value of the method to something, like this:

```
int someInt = Reservacion.cantNiños();
```

So when you call your method with the switch, you should have something like:

```
int lugarhostel = Reservacion.cantNiños();
Reservacion.switchReser(lugarhostel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The understanding of what happens here might take a while cause you posted alot of redundant to a question pieces. First of all it's not the right way to init lugarhostel variable inside some static method if you plan to use further. 
But assuming it could be a part of a class like:

```
public class Reservacion {
  int lugarhostel = 0;
}
```

Then you just need to use your methods via unaReser.method() where lugarhostel   would be a state of unaReser object though can be accessible and modifiable.
Read about pass by value mechanism java propose. It's the very important concept which come in place here. I suggest you to remove static keywords from everywhere and think about object Reservation you have. It should consist of a state and behavior which could update it's state. Basically state is a fields of an object which you can reference via dot operator like unaReser.lugarhostel. While behavior is basically are methods.

Your code suffers from a bad design which could greatly impact future maintenance. Every time you called static method like Reservacion.cantAdultos();
You doing nothing but creating local variable inside the method and returning it's value but without saving it to any reference variable in the main method. So try to think about fields:

```
public class Reservacion {
    int lugarhostel;
    int cantAdult;
    int cantNiños;
    int cantNoches;
    // behavior...
```

like about state of a Reservacion class for example. While cant*** methods could update Reservacion class object reference state, for example:

```
//behaviour..
public void Reservacion() {
    lugarhostel=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite 1 si desea reservar en playa o 2 para montaña"));
}

public void cantNoches(){
    cantNoches=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de noches"));
}

public void cant...
```

when you collect the state of the unaReser object you can pass it to static method for sth like this:

```
public static void switchReser(Reservacion unaReser) {
switch (unaReser.lugarhostel) {
        case 1:
            Reservacion.Playa(unaReser.cantAdult, unaReser.cantNiños, unaReser.cantNoches);
            break;
        case 2:
           Reservacion.Montaña(unaReser.cantAdult, unaReser.cantNiños, unaReser.cantNoches);
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion invalida");
            break;
    }
}
```

This would not be a perfect design either. But it would be a step forward for you in understanding OOP and basic java principles.